# How to snap line string start & end vertex to the nearest point?

Tags: postgis-2.0

I have a point layer and a line layer. The points are road junctions, collected using DGPS, while the lines are the connecting roads, collected through Handheld GPS in tracking mode. As a result, the lines are not actually connected to the points.

[image: Sample Network Image]

Now I want to:

1. Remove all intermediate nodes from each line string, to make it a straight line.
2. Snap the start & end vertex of lines to the nearest points.

I am using PostGIS 2.0.This by far what I have done:

```
UPDATE line
SET geom = ST_Simplify(geom, 1000);
```

Q. Is there any other better way to accomplish it?(Since I am using an absurd tolerance)

```
UPDATE line
SET geom = ST_AddPoint(
(SELECT geom FROM line WHERE id = 1),
(SELECT p.geom FROM point AS p, line AS l
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(p.geom,(SELECT ST_StartPoint(l.geom) FROM lt WHERE l.id=1)) LIMIT 1),
0)
WHERE id=1;
```

This will extend the line(with id=1) to the nearest point(point added at the beginning of the line).

Q. The above looks a bit complicated, is there any other efficient method/function available?

Comment: I made suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155749/how-to-snap-line-string-start-end-vertex-to-the-nearest-point - should I duplicate it here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need most of the data from the green lines, you could take a very simple (simplistic?) approach and make a a point file consisting of the start and end nodes of the green lines, attributed with a line ID.  Then use the [ST_Snap](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Snap.html) function to snap the new points to the existing intersections (red points).  Then use the [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) function to convert your snapped start/end points into your blue lines.